# How to do file operation in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
$fmonitorh(file_handler, conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4);
```

In this conv1, conv2... are my outputs and I want to write these values in text file, line by line or `,` between two values. While running above command I am getting values in one line only.

Answer (score 1):

the format of the file output command is:

```
$f...(file_handler, format_string, arg1, ...);
```

the `format_string` is the one which defines output layout and uses '%' specifiers to layout your data, similar to printf in 'c'.

so, you can use something like this:

```
$fmonitorh(file_handler, "%x\n%x\n%x\n%x", conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4);
```

Comment: Strongly suggest using $fdisplay or $fwrite instead of $fmonitor